# Unable to view source code in SonarQube on Firefox

Tags: sonarqube

I have a J2EE project using, which I am analyzing with Sonarqube using maven. But i am unable to view source code i.e drill down the code in Firefox when i click on issues. Everything works fine in chrome.
In Firefox i can't see any warnings or errors.

Here are the reference details about environment:
1)Firefox version 33.0.2
2)Maven 3.0
3)sonarqube 4.5.1
4)Pom.xml details

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>   


    <properties>    
        <sonar.host.url>http://domainname.com:8081</sonar.host.url>             
    </properties>
```

Could you please tell me what's the issue?

Comment: Please remove everything from your POM, you don't need all the information you have set, except the "sonar.host.url" property.

Comment: Thank Fabrice for your valuable comment.I followed the way you said   actually the problem is of browser compatibility supported in chrome but it doesn't open in Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any idea about problem with Firefox?

Comment: Please update your question then: which version of SonarQube? Which version of Firefox? Do you see an error on Firefox Javascript console that could explain the problem? Can you attach a screenshot?